# ¿Como hacer un bucle para leer y graficar diferentes base de datos en R?

Tags: bucles, rstudio

Tengo unas 20 base de datos en csv y me gustaría realizar el mismo grafico para cada una de ellas sin tener que reescrivir el codigo 20 veces. ¿Se podría usar algún bucle para hacerlo y  agilizar el proceso?

```
setwd("C:/Users/campi/Desktop/CSIC/R/Matrices")
datos<-read.table("C:/Users/campi/Desktop/CSIC/R/Matrices/Captain_T1_Sup.csv",sep=";",dec=",",header=TRUE)
attach(datos)
colnames(datos) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')

#install.packages("akima")
library(akima)
#install.packages("rgl")
library(rgl)

#interpolamos

XYZ=data.frame(x,y,z)
a_mat=interp(XYZ$x, XYZ$y, XYZ$z)
library(plotly)

#grafico interactivo de superficie 
fig <- plot_ly(x=a_mat$x, y=a_mat$y,z = a_mat$z)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface()
fig
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.